# Running custom checkstyle checks within a project

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I have a gradle-based project and would like to apply to it some custom checks which are in the same project, e.g. there is a package `com.my.package.checkstyle` and many other packages `com.my.package.*` with logic.

How could I do it?

Currently my checkstyle config imports checks like:

```
<module name="com.my.package.checkstyle.BracketsStructureCheck"/>
```

build.gradle has the following lines:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
compile('com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:6.17')
checkstyleMain.source = "src/main/java"
checkstyleMain.excludes = ["**/checkstyle/**"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would put your custom Checkstyle checks into a Gradle module of their own (say, `myChecks`), then reference that from the dependencies section of the main code module via a project dependency:

```java
dependencies {
    checkstyle project(':myChecks')
}
```

In this way, your custom checks get added to the classpath of the Checkstyle analysis and can be referenced from your *checkstyle.xml*.